# wget unicode filename errors

Tags: windows, unicode, filenames, wget, unicode-string

I am using wget (static build) on a Windows 7 machine to download a video file with unicode filename (in French).

```
wget http://someserver.com/Th%C3%A8me.mov
```

After the file downloads, I can view it in my folder as `ThΓ¨me.mov`. However the real proper name of the file is `Thème.mov`. I have tried setting `restrictfilenames = nocontrol` in wget.ini but didn't make any difference. How should I 'fix it'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug in wget](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37564). The `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` work-around only helps on Unix. On Windows, the best you can do is to use `--restrict-file-names=ascii` which will result in filenames like `Th%C3%A8me.mov`.

Comment: --restrict-file-names=nocontrol doesn't work for me on OS X. Any idea why?